# How can i enable password grant type in spring authorization server, i can see a way to set it in one of the abstract class of the library

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

My architecture is a microservice based architecutre and a single page application, where i want to use a client based authentication for inter service communication and password based authentication from a custom service i.e. a client asking for token on basis of password grant type, ideally it is not enabled for security reason, but i would want to override this and make my application have one single client for my own use to allow password grant type?

What will be the best way to achieve that

We have tried adding a custom password grant type and using that but in that case our client authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details about 'grand_type:password' in spring-authorization-server
: ["password" grant_type for token endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/126)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the how-to guide for [implementing an extension grant type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-ext-grant-type.html) to add support for the Password grant type.